# Calculation issue with the "lzyzsd/CircleProgress" GitHub project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, progress-bar

I have an issue with the [lzyzsd CircleProgress](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress) View.

This is my code:

```
        CircleProgress circle= (CircleProgress)v.findViewById(R.id.circle_progress);
        circle.setProgress();
        circle.setMax();
```

Only when I set in the setMax= 100 value and setProgress= 0-100 value I will get a logical answer (0-100%) but when I try to insert other values I will get wierd calculation. 
Example:

```
circle.setProgress(5);
circle.setMax(10);
```

Will give 5% instead of 50%

```
circle.setProgress(700);
circle.setMax(1000);
```

Will give 0% insted of 70%

```
circle.setProgress(77);
circle.setMax(1000);
```

Will also give 70%

Can someone explain this please and how should I work it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution for this problem.

Apparently I had to normalize my numbers so it will be relative to 100.

setMax() should be 100

setProgress() should be claculated like so- (oldProgress*100)/oldMax

*This calculation should be calculated into float value (use 100.0f) and then you can round it with Math.round.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change order: first `setMax()` and then `setProgress()`.
Because otherwise the progress will be calculated on the default value for max, which is 100.

No matter if you you set the max to a different value **after**: the progress value as already been set.
Hence, the unexpected value (which is actually correct).

Comment: You didn't even try

Comment: The change in the order will change the outcome but it still remains with wrong output- arcLodging.setMax(1000);
        arcLodging.setProgress(77); will give 77% and

Comment: `arcLodging.setMax(1000); arcLodging.setProgress(77); will give 77%` must give **7.7%**

Comment: That`s exactly what i`m saying! When I`m running it, i`m getting a messed up calculations.